# Passing opencv2 cv::Mat among processes programming in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, opencv, ipc, shared-memory

I would develop a real time computer vision system where a C++ application produces cv::Mat images, grayscale and color, while other processes analyze the images.

The system should have low latency and should avoid unnecessary memory copies.

Are there any library, or standard technique, for sharing and synchronizing cv::Mat among processes?

Edit: the processes that should share the cv::Math are illustrated [in the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc5Ku.png)

Comment: boost has a nice shared memory library: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html.

Comment: Note that you might need to add some management code to mirror the cv::Mat header and data into the shated memory, and to restore it in the receiving process. boost has some built in shared memory oriented classes (which are similar to std containers and more), but I don't think you'll get full support for cv::Mat out of the box.

Comment: A high level way is to use remote processing calling like Apache Thrift. For serialisation of cv::Mat data you can use cv::imencode as ".bmp" and cv::imdecode

Comment: Interprocess communications needs kernel mode calls. May be you can use multithreading model?

Comment: if you send blobs over local tcp network it will work fine.